# ASP.Net WInforms ListView Checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listview where I can add items to a listview with an option to checkmark it.  I can add as many items as I want, but only 1 item can be checked.  This is my base value, and the other items I add (that would be unchecked) are used for comparison (ValuesToExport).  Before I had the listViewExportList_ItemCheck event, I had the contents of that function in the GenerateReport() function, inside the foreach loop.  When I ran it, if I have more than 1 box selected and try to generate report, it'll give me the error about only selecting one 1 base value like expected, but I don't even want the option of selecting more than one box.  My thought was, going through and unchecking the boxes that I try after the first one (or have all of them unchecked) if the error is thrown.  When including the ItemCheck event, after checking 2 items, an error occurs that just shows the message.  This is WinForms which doesn't include a HTML Markup.  Here's my code.

```
 private void GenerateReport()
    {
        DataObjects.Collections.Values valuesToExport = new ValueApp.DataObjects.Collections.Values();
        DataObjects.Value baseValue = null;


        foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewExportList.Items)
        {
            if (item.Checked)
            {
                basevalue = DataAccess.valueDb.User.value.Fill(((DataObjects.value)item.Tag).valueID);

            }
            else
            {
                valuesToExport.Add(DataAccess.valueDb.User.value.Fill(((DataObjects.value)item.Tag).valueID));
            }

        }



        if (basevalue == null)
        {
            throw new Data.Common.ErrorHandling.UserFeedbackException("Please select a base value.  This value will be compared to all other value’s.");
        }
        else if (valuesToExport.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new Data.Common.ErrorHandling.UserFeedbackException("Please add an value for comparison.");
        }
        else
        {

            Reports.valueFeatureComparison.GenerateReport(basevalue, valuesToExport, this.chkIgnoreFeatureRev.Checked, this.chkIgnoreSignalFeature.Checked);
        }
    }




private void listViewExportList_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {

        int numChecked = 0;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewExportList.Items)
        {
            if (item.Checked)
            {
                numChecked++;
            }

        }
        if (numChecked > 1)
        {
            throw new Data.Common.ErrorHandling.UserFeedbackException("Only 1 Base value can be selected.");
        }





    }
```

Comment: Solved my own problem.

Comment: Console.Write(e.CurrentValue.ToString());
            if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                if (listViewExportList.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewExportList.CheckedItems)
                    {
                        item.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }